# Gravity forms doesn't update entry but instead create a new one

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

**Context**

We've created (I actually inherited code) few forms with Gravity forms. One of the form is used to manage profil informations.

**Description**

The form doesn't update entries but instead creates new entries. Therefore the result is that in the profil page we have the initial information if we modify and save, after reload nothing changes. But, in the database, a new entry is created.

**Tried solution**

Setting a field to be unique doesn't fix it but returns an error saying that the value used in the field has already been used.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the entry ID before the entry is saved. This example from the [gform_entry_id_pre_save_lead](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_entry_id_pre_save_lead/#examples) documentation will help:

```
add_filter( 'gform_entry_id_pre_save_lead', 'my_update_entry_on_form_submission', 10, 2 );
function my_update_entry_on_form_submission( $entry_id, $form ) {
    $update_entry_id = rgpost( 'my_update_entry_id' );
    return $update_entry_id ? $update_entry_id : $entry_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers David, unfortunatelty I'm still getting the same answer. I've replaced 'my_update_entry_id' by 'lead_id' which is the name of the field to fetch the data from the DB.

Comment: Is it actually "lead_id" in the $_POST? Try doing a `print_r( $_POST )` to see the data submitted and make sure your value is where you expect it.